# KeyError when using loc from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple CSV-file which I import as a dataframe. Using `df.columns` I get the following:

`Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'age', 'sex', 'bmi', 'bp', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 'target'], dtype='object')`

So there definitely is a column named `sex`. When now using

`df.loc["sex"]`

I get the following output:

```
  File "c:/Users/xxx/OneDrive - Universität Paderborn/Universität/SS_21/Python_Kurse/Hello-World.py", line 37, in <module>
    df.loc["axe"]
  File "C:\xxxx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 895, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\xxxxx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1124, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\xxxx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1073, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\xxxx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3739, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\xxxx\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 354, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'axe'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to give index like

```
df.loc[index,"sex"]
```

For example:

```
df.loc[1,"sex"]
```

If you only want to get sex column:

```
df["sex"]
```